# Cannot add packages to Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am trying to add some packages to my solution in xamarin studio like "restsharp", and I get the following error :

"Adding RestSharp... Adding 'RestSharp 104.4.0' to sibuf. Could not install package 'RestSharp 104.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

I tried to change MonoAndroid version and it still not working.

Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RestSharp NuGet package does not include any assemblies that are compatible with Android projects.

I would look at using [RestSharp](https://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp/) from Xamarin's Component Store instead. This component supports Android and iOS projects.

Answer (score 0):

Or [HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) from Microsoft. It is on NuGet and PCL compatible.

Answer (score 0):

add  Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6 into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6\PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip

which you will need to unzip and extract the contents into the directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable